# Swift: Print separator not adding a space between array items

Tags: swift, printing

I have this code:

```
let newArray = [4, 6, 7, 12].reversed().map{print($0, terminator:"")}
```

and it give me this output:

```
12764
```

I was expecting: 12 7 6 4

How do I output this with a space between integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you explicitly tell the `print` statement to put an empty `String` as a terminator, hence the issue. If you changed `terminator` to `" "`, your code would work fine.

Btw it makes no sense to `map` the result of `print`, which is `Void`. I suppose you simply wanted to call `forEach` instead.

```
[4, 6, 7, 12].reversed().forEach{print($0, terminator:" ")}
```

To actually see the output, you'll also need to call `print("")`, since the print buffer is only flushed to the console on newlines and since in the `forEach` the terminator is explicitly set to a space, there's no new line added there.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a misuse of print. Why not use `joined(separator:)` to build your output string:

```
let output = [4, 6, 7, 12].reversed().map { String($0) }.joined(separator: " ")

print("\"" + newArray + "\"")
```

That will only insert spaces between elements, it won't put an undesired space at the end, and then it will only output a single newline at the end to flush the output to the console.

The output of the above is

```
"12 7 6 4"
```

Comment: The task was to print the integers on one line with spaces, not convert them to a string.

Comment: And my solution does that. It builds an output string, and then prints it.